# How to create a dependent dropdown (as subcategory)

Tags: python, django, drop-down-menu, categories

I want to have a dropdown menu which shows all item from a choice list. The picture below shows all my items from 'Category' which is hardcoded. How can I iterate through my choice field and fill their values into my dropdown menu?

But more importantly is that I want that my dropdown menu for 'Product' should only show the choices related to my selection for 'Category'.

[image: 1]

I think its too complicated to create for all of them each a class. I want to do it by an if else like: If (get.Category).is Selected then iterate: for item in 'products' present as option.

Im new in coding so I am not sure where to put my variables.

my filter_list.html

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="inputState">Product</label>
            <select id="inputState2" name="item" class="form-control">
                <option selected>Choose...</option>
                {% for item in transactionSubCategory %}
                <option value="{{item.value}}">{{item.title}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
                <option value="banana">banana</option>
                <option value="orange">orange</option>
                <option value="strawberry">strawberry</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

my models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
content = models.TextField(default='SOME STRING')
date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
post = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='SOME STRING')

category_choices = (
    ('fruits', 'Fruits'),
    ('nuts', 'Nuts'),
    ('tea', 'Tea'),
    ('oil', 'Oil'),
    ('flowers', 'Flowers'),
    ('veggies', 'Veggies'),
    ('honey', 'Honey'),
    ('legumes', 'Legumes'),
    ('wheat', 'Wheat'),
    ('mushroom', 'Mushroom'),
)

fruit_choices= (
    ('apple', 'apple'),
    ('orange', 'orange'),
    ('strawberry', 'strawberry'),
    ('coconut', 'coconut'),
    ('watermelon', 'watermelon'),
    ('banana', 'banana'),
    ('peach', 'peach'),
    ('kiwi', 'kiwi'),
    ('avocado', 'avocado'),
    ('cherry', 'cherry'),


  )
category = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=category_choices, default=0)
product = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=fruit_choices, default=0)
```

views.py

```
def filter_list(request):#BootstrapFilterView(request)
qs = Post.objects.all()
categories = Post.category

products = Post.product#.fruit_choices #Post.products
city = Post.city_choices
price = Post.price

title_contains_query = request.GET.get('title_contains')
categories_query = request.GET.get('category')
product_query = request.GET.get('product')
city_query = request.GET.get('city')
price_query = request.GET.get('product')
amount_query = request.GET.get('amount')


transactionSubCategory = Post.objects.filter(category=categories_query)



#Title
if title_contains_query != '' and title_contains_query is not None:
    qs = qs.filter(title__icontains=title_contains_query)
#category
if is_valid_queryparam(categories_query) and categories_query != 'Choose...':
    qs = qs.filter(category__iexact=categories_query)
# subcategory
#if is_valid_queryparam(subcategories_query) and subcategories_query != 'Choose...':
    #qs = qs.filter(subcategory__iexact=subcategories_query) #parent_category__id=target_category.id
#product
if is_valid_queryparam(product_query) and product_query != 'Choose...':
    qs = qs.filter(product__iexact=product_query)
#city
if is_valid_queryparam(city_query) and city_query != 'Choose...':
    qs = qs.filter(city__iexact=city_query)
#price
if is_valid_queryparam(price_query) and price_query != 'Price':
    qs = qs.filter(price__iexact=price_query)
#Menge
if is_valid_queryparam(amount_query) and amount_query != 'Menge':
    qs = qs.filter(amount__iexact=amount_query)


context = {
    'queryset': qs,
    'category' : categories,
    'product' : products,
    'city' : city,
    'price' : price,
    'transactionSubCategory': transactionSubCategory,
}
return render(request, 'digitalFarm/filter_list.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question (correct me if I'm wrong), when you select some catagory - you only want options belonging to that category in your product choices.
You can achieve this easily by using some JavaScript.

You can add a class to each option, which tells you it's category. It will look something like this :

```
{% for item in transactionSubCategory %}
        <option class="{{item.category}} product-option" value="{{item.product}}">{{item.title}}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Note, I have removed the `"{{item.value}}"` from your `option`. This is because `item` has no attribute called value. I have used `"{{item.product}}"` instead because that's what it looked like you wanted there from your hard-coded examples.

The class will be an excellent selector to make the javascript changes that you need. But first we need to answer your first question.

> **The picture below shows all my items from 'Category' which is hardcoded. How can I iterate through my choice field and fill their
> values into my dropdown menu?**

To do this, we need to pass all categories to your frontend. Here's one way you would do that -
In views.py:

```
categories = [x[0] for x in Post.category_choices] #Assuming categories is supposed to do this.
```

In template:

```
<select id="categories" name="item" class="form-control">
    {% for item in category%}
        <option value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

So that's the first part of your question.
Now, coming to the second part here's what we could do -
Every time your category selection is changed: Hide all options in product options, and show only the values corresponding to the selected category.

Here's how you would do that in JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("categories").onchange= function(e){
        var elemsToHide = document.getElementsByClassName("product-option")
        for(var i = 0; i < elemsToHide.length; i++){
            elemsToHide[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        var elemsToShow = document.getElementsByClassName(e.target.value) 
        //e.target.value Contains the selected option value, which is the classname for elements to be shown
        for(var i = 0; i < elemsToShow.length; i++){
            elemsToHide[i].style.display = "unset";
        }
    }
```